# onTouch movement for ImageView?

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I am relatively new to Android development.

But I was wondering **whether it is possible to move these images, so they can swap with each other in a grid**. As it is a board game I am trying to implement.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnyta.png

The code for the array of images:

```
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, 
        R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, 
        R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, 
        R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.empty, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg,
        R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, 
        R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, 
        R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.peg, R.drawable.blank, R.drawable.blank,
        };
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView  
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement drag and drop for your game?

Comment: no, you press on a peg to select it, then press on a empty space to move it there. You don't need to drag it.

Comment: you should see drag and drop. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Would that work with my code though? because the elements in the array  don't have individual id's. Check my xml in the main post.

Comment: @user1902535 i have not tried it. Drag and drop should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need drag and drop this should be simple enough.

```
private View firstClicked = null;

private OnClickListener swapImages = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(firstClicked != null){
            LayoutParams p1 = firstClicked.getLayoutParams();
            LayoutParams p2 = v.getLayoutParams();
            v.setLayoutParams(p1);
            firstClicked.setLayoutParams(p2);
                            firstClicked = null;
        }
        else 
            firstClicked = v;
    }
};
```

This way you just swap their positions, not images inside them.

EDIT: but if this interfere with your game logic, you just swap instead of layout parameters, you just swap their images.

EDIT: This code swaps your drawables, you need to create your own logic

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;


public class Game extends Activity {

private ImageView firstClicked = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game);

            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Game.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(firstClicked != null){
                    ImageView v2 = (ImageView)v;
                    Drawable d2 = v2.getDrawable();
                    Drawable d1 = firstClicked.getDrawable();
                    v2.setImageDrawable(d1);
                    firstClicked.setImageDrawable(d2);
                    firstClicked = null;
                }
                else {
                    firstClicked = (ImageView)v;
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Would this go in the ImageAdapter?

Comment: It didn't work for me. These are my files: http://pastebin.com/x2yattZv ...  http://pastebin.com/Q2jiRXUS